# Can we use the sample standard deviation instead of the population standard deviation in the z-test formula?

Tags: statistics

[image]

I need to test $\mu_1 - \mu_2 = 0$, but they gave me the sample sd instead of the population sd. there's no way i can get the population sd if it's not given.

Comment: also i have u1-u2 = 4, is do = 4? how is 4 the standard deviation, we are subtracting a mean from another mean?

Comment: There is a t-test given by $\frac {x^-\mu_0}{s/n^{1/2}}$ that with n-1 degrees of freedom, that allows you to determine if the population mean $\mu$ is equal to $\mu_0$. Maybe you can adapt it to your situation by fixing one of the sample means and comparing it to the other one.

Comment: also, is it possible that a sample with n > 30 is considered a population instead of a sample?

Comment: No a sample is derived from a subset of the population.

Comment: sample size are 30 and 40. in the textbook we have an example with n = 40 and n = 60. they use that z equation.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing i am wondering because they say to use the z-test when sample size is greater than 30.

Comment: also, one last question if x > z value, we reject Ho right (no matter what test we use)?

Comment: It's okay to replace the population variances $\sigma_1^2,\sigma_2^2$ with the sample variances simply because they're consistent estimators.

Comment: See also http://www.isixsigma.com/tools-templates/hypothesis-testing/making-sense-two-sample-t-test